# Matlab: How to plot this fourier series, where each index is odd

Tags: matlab

[image]

How do I enter the formula shown above? I can't seem to get n = 1, 3, 5, ...
I tried different code along the line of this:

```
syms k x
x = 1/2 + symsum(k^2, k, [1:2:15])
```

But there is an error message.

Also, on a side note, what's the purpose of syms and the "x" variable shown in the matlab documentation example where I got this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are not committed to using `symsum`, here is one way:

```
t = [0:0.01:4]; % time grid
n = [1:2:15];   % range of n

x = 0.5 + sum(2/pi*diag(1./n)*sin(pi*n(:)*t(:)')); % summation

% plot
figure;
plot(t, x);
xlabel('t');
ylabel('x');
```

Just in case you're new to Matlab, the following are some explanation for what's going on here:

- `n(:)` is a column vector
- `t(:)'` is r row vector
- So, the product `n(:)*t(:)'` is the matrix of `n` times `t` terms in the original equation. Each column in the matrix corresponds to a fixed point in `t`.
- The term `diag(1./n)*` scales each row of the above-mentioned matrix to take care of the divide-by-`n` operation in the original equation.
- Finally, `sum()` collapses the matrix into one row whose elements are sums of individual columns.

[image: Here's a plot of results obtained by evaluating the above code.]

Answer (score 1):

The `syms` statement at the top of the code is used to say that names `x` and `k` will represent symbolic variables, which behave very differently to usual numerical variables. Symbolic variables allow you to do computations using symbols, as in calculus where the variables can have any values in the set of real numbers. It is not always necessary to use `syms` to plot, and you could go with @aksadv's answer if that were the case.

Now to your coding question. To get the sum using `syms` for the uneven numbers in the range you have two choices: use `sum` or `symsum`. `symsum` allows you to perform symbolic summations of series, the limitation is that the terms of the sum have to be spaced by steps of size `1`. This can be achieved because you could rewrite `k` as `2m+1` where `m=0,1,..,7`. The other option is to use `sum` where you just have to get an array of functions where each element corresponds to a value of `k` that you want and then call `sum` on that array.

### Using `symsum`

```
syms k,x
y = 1/2 + symsum(2/pi/(2*k+1).*sin((2*k+1)*pi*x),k,0,7)
```

### Using `sum`

```
syms x
y = 1/2 + sum(2/pi./(1:2:15).*sin((1:2:15)*pi*x))
```